# How to set Notepad++ GUI text to a bigger font?

Tags: fonts, notepad++, user-interface

I can't seem to find anything about this topic anywhere on the net, so I am asking here.

Is there any way to increase visual font styles of the interface's text of Npp?

I am not talking about the visual styles of the source code's font, but rather the menus, buttons and stuff ( the User interface ).

I want to help by dad to use more advanced text editors, but the interface's text is too damn small and he need to put a glasses to read it.

The interface text is very small on those... File, Edit, Search and so on. I tried to use the "Style configurator", but it only sets the font size such as how your source is displayed and it does not have settings for increasing the interface font at all.

Comment: The toolbar icon sizes can be increased. I am not sure about the menubar because I think the text size there is very much fixed. You can use the toolbar to get most of the basic jobs done and it is easier too. Will that help?

Comment: Nope, because he has to be used to all those new Icons. So far he is using PE2.exe in text mode. I was hoping for some kind of internal Npp hack, because When I make the font on WinXP  bigger, Npp's GUI is not affected.

It will be nice if there are any alternatives, which support that functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI is made of standard windows drawing primitives. That means standard controls apply to them. You can change the overall [appearance of all windows menu fonts](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-windows-fonts#1TC=windows-7) or you can use [DPI scaling](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller?v=t).
Windows 10 Creators Update (1703) has a [new DPI scaling mechanism](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/04/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-desktop-applications-windows-10-creators-update/) that should help more with applications like Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

**In Notepad++**

1. **Settings > Preferences**
   (Open Preferences from the menu bar)
2. **General > Tab Bar**
   Tab Bar options are outlined on the right hand side of general preferences.

   - Ensure the "Reduce" checkbox is unchecked. It reduces the font size of opened file tabs to tiny.
   - Ensure "Draw a colored bar on active tab" is checked and experiment with removing "Darken Inactive tabs" to see if it produces a beneficial result.

This solved the issue for me under Windows 10, using a Notepad++ build of 25th Sep 2022. after previously customizing "Ease of Access > Display" choices in Windows settings as best I could.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it by changing the registry key...

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes\MS Shell Dlg`

to something like...

`Arial Unicode MS`

The prior value of that key on my Windows 10 machine was "[Microsoft Sans Serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sans_Serif)", an older font that I had some problems with before in another app. So, although changing the font substitution (as shown above) is a system-wide setting that will affect all of the (legacy) apps on your system, in this case I didn't worry about it too much. Especially since, in my opinion, the situation with the Notepad++ UI font couldn't get much worse.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct UI graphics from the executable properties on the Compatibility tab.  Unchecked Compatibility Mode.  Unchecked all High DPI settings.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this better than the answer from seven years ago?