# Some text fonts too large

Tags: windows-10, fonts

This is a `Windows` problem, not `Notepad++`. Please re-open the question.

I found the solution though:
[image]
Clicking the `Restore default font settings` button does the trick.

---

I'm not sure how it happened but some programs in `Windows` have text which is too large now. For example [`Notepad++`](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/):
[image]
It only happens on some texts and applications, not all. Even Java Swing programs are affected. The `display settings` font size is still set to the recommended 100% so that's not it:
[image]
How do I fix my font size problem to what it was before/supposed to be?

Comment: I don't see any too large fonts in your screenshot.

Comment: The `new 1` is the "large font" I'm referring to

Comment: I've voted to reopen your questiion, but it'll also need votes from others. Please remove the solution from it, you'll be able to post it as an answer once it'll be reopened.

Comment: I'll wait till it's re-opened to place the answer and remove it from the question so it doesn't get lost or something